# Renaming multiple column values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace, rename

I have customer reviews stored in a Pandas column 'Sentiment'. This is the result of `data['Sentiment'].unique()`:

```
array(['Negative', 'Positive', '?', 'Neutral', 'nan', 'positive',
       'neutral', 'negative', 'Neg', 'ppos', 'ne'], dtype=object)
```

I am trying to group the values into 'positive', 'negative', and 'neutral' and created the three mapping lists:

```
positive = ['Positive','positive', 'ppos']
negative = ['Negative', 'negative', 'Neg']
neutral = ['Neutral', 'neutral', 'ne']
```

Everything else should be NAn. I had a try with `iterrows()` along the lines of:

```
for idx, row in data.iterrows():
    if row['Sentiment'].isin(positive):
        row['Sentiment'] == 'positive'
               ...
```

Doesn't work and does not seem efficient either. I tried with Series and booleans and it seems a promising approach but I really wonder if there is some succinct workaround.

Comment: should be `df.loc[idx,'Sentiment'] = 'positive'` and so on. But then again, other solutions with `map` and `np.select` are much better.

Answer (score 3):

Use [numpy.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). Pass conditions as the first argument, the values corresponding to conditions as second and the default value which doesn't match any condition.

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [
    df['Sentiment'].isin(positive),
    df['Sentiment'].isin(neutral),
    df['Sentiment'].isin(negative)
]
values = ['positive', 'neutral', 'negative']

df['Sentiment'] = np.select(conditions, values, np.nan)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.apply`

```
def sentiment_group(sentiment):
    if sentiment in ['Positive','positive', 'ppos']:
        return 'positive'
    if sentiment in ['Negative', 'negative', 'Neg']:
        return 'negative'
    if sentiment in ['Neutral', 'neutral', 'ne']:
        return 'neutral'
    else:
        return sentiment

data['sentiment_group'] = data['Sentiment'].apply(sentiment_group)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary, pairing the old values to the new, and replace the contents of the Sentiments column via pandas' [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
  #list of old and new values
old_values = [['Positive','positive', 'ppos'],
              ['Negative', 'negative', 'Neg'],
              ['Neutral', 'neutral', 'ne']]

new_values = ['positive','negative','neutral']

merge = zip(new_values,old_values)

#create mapping
d = {}
for new, old in merge:
    for i in old:
        d[i] = new

print(d)

{'Positive': 'positive',
 'positive': 'positive',
 'ppos': 'positive',
 'Negative': 'negative',
 'negative': 'negative',
 'Neg': 'negative',
 'Neutral': 'neutral',
 'neutral': 'neutral',
 'ne': 'neutral'}

#apply mapping to series:
df.Sentiment.map(d)
```